# Mysql column to utf8_bin

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql. I want to change one of the columns to have utf8_bin as it's collate attribute. 
I know the command to do for whole table is like:
ALTER TABLE temp CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

But how do I do it for individual columns?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's right in [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html)

Their example

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY
    col1 VARCHAR(5)
      CHARACTER SET latin1
      COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```